# Magento2 is not loading di:compile generated files

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, code-generation

I am trying to load `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory` in a plugin using the `ObjectManager` injected in the Plugin constructor. The file `var\generation\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory.php` does exist. When I run `$this->customerExtensionFactory = $objectManager->get(self::CUSTOMER_EXTENSION_FACTORY_PATH);` in my Plugin it throws an error: `"Notice: Undefined index: instance in \/vagrant\/data\/magento2\/lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php on line 222"`

My Plugin code is this:

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Model\Plugin\Card;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager;

class MyPlugin
{
    const CUSTOMER_EXTENSION_FACTORY_PATH = 'Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $customerExtensionFactory;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory
         */
        $this->customerExtensionFactory = $objectManager->get(self::CUSTOMER_EXTENSION_FACTORY_PATH);
    }

    public function afterGetDataModel(Customer $customer, $customerDataObject)
    {
        $extension = $this->customerExtensionFactory->create()->setOpenpayCard('aaa-123');
        $customerDataObject->setExtensionAttributes($extension);

        return $customerDataObject;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what that may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need ObjectManager. Here is a reworked version:

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Model\Plugin\Card;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class MyPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $customerExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory $customerExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CustomerExtensionFactory $customerExtensionFactory)
    {
        $this->customerExtensionFactory = $customerExtensionFactory;
    }

    public function afterGetDataModel(Customer $customer, $customerDataObject)
    {
        $extension = $this->customerExtensionFactory->create()->setOpenpayCard('aaa-123');
        $customerDataObject->setExtensionAttributes($extension);
        return $customerDataObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right! I actually did this and it worked. I did not know how DI worked in the Plugins. Is there other way to inject objects other than annotations?

Comment: Here are more details about DI in magento2 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html